# Radio button cannot return different state

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, firebase

I am fairly new to developing web app using React.js and Firebase so pardon me if my question doesn't seems relevant.

I have this simple web app where user can choose an option from multiple choices using radio button. When the user finished answering the questions, they will submit their answers and the answers will be submitted to the Firebase.

Now I'm stuck at writing the chosen value to the Firebase. There are 2 issues for me:

1) The radio button can only be clicked once. Meaning that users cannot answer the second question without the first answer being deselected.

2) When I clicked on submit, all the other option returns the same values as the chosen option.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import firebase from './firebase.js';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
          super();
          this.state = {
              owl: '',
              house: ''
        };

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
            <ol type="1">
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>

            <li><p>What is the name of Harry Potter's owl?</p></li>
                <ol type="a">
                <div className="radio">
                    <label>
                        <li><input type="radio" name="owl" value="hedwig" checked={this.state.owl === "hedwig"} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                        Hedwig<br></br></li>
                        <li><input type="radio" name="owl" value="ron" checked={this.state.owl === "ron"} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                        Ron <br></br></li>
                        <li><input type="radio" name="owl" value="brian" checked={this.state.owl === "brian"} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                        Brian</li>
                        <br></br>
                        <br></br>
                    </label>
                </div>
                </ol>

            <li><p>What is the name of Cho Chang's house?</p></li>
                <ol type="a">
                <div className="radio">
                    <label>
                        <li><input type="radio" name="house" value="gryffindor" checked={this.state.house === "gryffindor"} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                        Gryffindor<br></br></li>
                        <li><input type="radio" name="house" value="slytherin" checked={this.state.house === "slytherin"} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                        Slytherin <br></br></li>
                        <li><input type="radio" name="house" value="ravenclaw" checked={this.state.house === "ravenclaw"} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                        Ravenclaw</li>
                        <br></br>
                        <br></br>
                    </label>
                </div>
                </ol>

            <button>Submit!</button>
            </form>
            </ol>
            </div>
        )
    }

    handleChange = (e) =>{
        this.setState({
            owl: e.target.value,
            house: e.target.value
        });
    }

    handleSubmit = (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault();
        const itemsRef = firebase.database().ref('answers');
        const item = {
            owl: this.state.owl,
            house: this.state.house
        }
        itemsRef.push(item);
        this.setState({
            owl: '',
            house: ''
        });
    }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer already, after 12 hours of searching and staring at the code.

I just needed to set a unique name for the onChange method. Here's what I have done.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import firebase from './firebase.js';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
          super();
          this.state = {
              owl: '',
              house: ''
        };

        //owlChange and houseChange are now exclusively for owl and house values respectively
        this.owlChange = this.owlChange.bind(this);
        this.houseChange = this.houseChange.bind(this);

        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
            <ol type="1">
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>

            <li><p>What is the name of Harry Potter's owl?</p></li>
                <ol type="a">
                <div className="radio">
                    <label>
                        <li><input type="radio" name="owl" value="hedwig" checked={this.state.owl === "hedwig"} onChange={this.owlChange}/>
                        Hedwig<br></br></li>
                        <li><input type="radio" name="owl" value="ron" checked={this.state.owl === "ron"} onChange={this.owlChange}/>
                        Ron <br></br></li>
                        <li><input type="radio" name="owl" value="brian" checked={this.state.owl === "brian"} onChange={this.owlChange}/>
                        Brian</li>
                        <br></br>
                        <br></br>
                    </label>
                </div>
                </ol>

            <li><p>What is the name of Cho Chang's house?</p></li>
                <ol type="a">
                <div className="radio">
                    <label>
                        <li><input type="radio" name="house" value="gryffindor" checked={this.state.house === "gryffindor"} onChange={this.houseChange}/>
                        Gryffindor<br></br></li>
                        <li><input type="radio" name="house" value="slytherin" checked={this.state.house === "slytherin"} onChange={this.houseChange}/>
                        Slytherin <br></br></li>
                        <li><input type="radio" name="house" value="ravenclaw" checked={this.state.house === "ravenclaw"} onChange={this.houseChange}/>
                        Ravenclaw</li>
                        <br></br>
                        <br></br>
                    </label>
                </div>
                </ol>

            <button>Submit!</button>
            </form>
            </ol>
            </div>
        )
    }

    owlChange = (e) =>{
        this.setState({
            owl: e.target.value
        });
    }

    houseChange = (e) =>{
        this.setState({
            house: e.target.value
        });
    }

    handleSubmit = (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault();
        const itemsRef = firebase.database().ref('answers');
        const item = {
            owl: this.state.owl,
            house: this.state.house
        }
        itemsRef.push(item);
        this.setState({
            owl: '',
            house: ''
        });
    }
}

export default App;
```